# Qtip2: How to temporarily disable qtip2

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip, qtip2

When I drag an object in the screen, I do not want qtip2 to display anything (since mouse is moving, it may enter area of other object and show tooltip) until I drop current object.

Hence I need something that could temporarily disable all qtip events.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: `$('.qtip').qtip('disable');` does that work?

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work, though it seems that it should.